# Call to a member function verifyInput() on a non-object

Tags: php, email, syntax

It seems like a pretty common problem but I can't see to find the answer to my problem. I have been getting the dreaded "Call to a member function verifyInput() on a non-object" fatal error.

```
<?php

// empty values
$name = $email = $topic = $message = "";
$nameErr = $emailErr = $topicErr = $messageErr = "";

// link the name tags in HTML
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    /* name if */
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $nameErr = "&nbsp;* Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    }

    /* email if */
    if ( ! empty($_POST['email'])) {
        if ($email->verifyInput($_POST['email'], 6)){
            $fill['email'] = $_POST['email']; //$fill is the array of values passed
        } else {
            $emailErr = "&nbsp;* Email is incorrect - Try Again";
        }
        } else {
            $emailErr = "&nbsp;* Email is required";
    }

    // Form content
    $recipient = "generic@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $formcontent = "4 Days of Fun.ca -
                \n\n\nFrom: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $topic
                \n\n\nMessage: $message";
    $mailheader = "From: $email - Subject: $topic \r\n";

    //function to send mail
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank you for contacting us, $name! \nWe will respond to you soon!";

    }

//function for test_input
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

// Validation of Inputs
function verifyInput($input, $type){
    if ($type == 0)     $pattern =  '/^1$/';//just the number 1
        elseif ($type == 1) $pattern =  '/^[0-9]+$/';//just integers
        elseif ($type == 2) $pattern =  '/^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü]+$/';//just letters
        elseif ($type == 3) $pattern =  '/^[0-9A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü]+$/';//integers & letters
        elseif ($type == 4) $pattern =  '/^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-ú0-9àÀÜü\s()\/\'":\*,.;\-!?&#$@]{1,1500}$/';//text
        elseif ($type == 5) $pattern =  '/^[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü0-9\']+[A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü0-9 \'\-\.]+$/';//name
        elseif ($type == 6) $pattern = '/^.+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,}$/';//e-mail
        elseif ($type == 7) $pattern = '/^((\(0?[1-9][0-9]\))|(0?[1-9][0-9]))?[ -.]?([1-9][0-9]{3})[ -.]?([0-9]{4})$/';//brazilian phone
        if (preg_match($pattern, $input) == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

?>
```

This is where the error is in question:`if ($email->verifyInput($_POST['email'], 6)){` however I'm confused... I looked it up and everywhere states that the variable passed in ie `$email` may not be an object. But the variable is declared as an object here: `$email = $_POST['email'];` is it not? Or am I missing something big and obvious?

I just started learning PHP but I've got a lot of foundational knowledge with C++, so there are a lot of similarities I already get... This is not one of them.

Maybe I'm just not understanding the `->` operator, or maybe it's a non-object because of something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$email->verifyInput()` would call the method (function) `verifyInput()` that is included in the class `email`, but here i can see that your function is not a member of any class, so if you need to call this fuction you just have to change:

```
if ($email->verifyInput($_POST['email'], 6)){...
```

to:

```
if (verifyInput($_POST['email'], 6)){...
```

And regarding your question about `->`:

As i mentioned above `->` is used after the instantiated class followed by the member or the method name. probably you need to read more about PHP, i would suggest [this course](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/php), or you can jump directly to get a course about PHP OOP [right here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-ZQQ64/0/1).

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfect. I think I understand too, so by putting `$email` in there it's assuming that the function `verifyInput` is called from within a class named `email`? Whereas my function is actually global?

Comment: That's perfectly correct, i edited my answer and added some resources so you can know more about `PHP OOP`, cheers.